Rust tracing not generating span IDs or associating with parents
I have a tracing subscriber like:
let subscriber = tracing_subscriber::registry().with(
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::layer()
            .compact()
            .with_file(true)
            .with_line_number(true)
            .with_span_events(FmtSpan::CLOSE)
            .with_target(false)
            // .json()
            .with_filter(level_filters::LevelFilter::from_level(Level::DEBUG))
    );

    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber).unwrap();

But the logs and spans are not getting IDs generated (and thus not being associated with a parent/current span). What do I need to fix so that spans have IDs generated, are associated with parents, and logs have the current span id in them? I am tracing like #[tracing::instrument(level = "debug", skip(state))] and logging like
debug!(
                "Getting subslice of value for key {} with start={} end={}",
                key, start, end
            );

Generated logs look like:
2024-06-23T12:37:08.371471Z DEBUG get_or_list_prefix:get_item:root:outer_child: src/routes/get.rs:74: close time.busy=5.38µs time.idle=5.71µs key_prefix=Some("a") params=GetOrListParams { list: None, limit: None, with_vals: None, reverse: None, start: None, end: None } params=GetOrListParams { list: None, limit: None, with_vals: None, reverse: None, start: None, end: None } key="a"
2024-06-23T12:37:08.371534Z  INFO get_or_list_prefix:get_item:root: src/routes/get.rs:71: close time.busy=86.0µs time.idle=3.67µs key_prefix=Some("a") params=GetOrListParams { list: None, limit: None, with_vals: None, reverse: None, start: None, end: None } params=GetOrListParams { list: None, limit: None, with_vals: None, reverse: None, start: None, end: None } key="a"
2024-06-23T12:37:08.371606Z DEBUG get_or_list_prefix:get_item: src/routes/get.rs:65: close time.busy=163µs time.idle=7.37µs key_prefix=Some("a") params=GetOrListParams { list: None, limit: None, with_vals: None, reverse: None, start: None, end: None } params=GetOrListParams { list: None, limit: None, with_vals: None, reverse: None, start: None, end: None } key="a"
2024-06-23T12:37:08.371637Z DEBUG get_or_list_prefix: src/routes/get.rs:41: close time.busy=216µs time.idle=16.9µs key_prefix=Some("a") params=GetOrListParams { list: None, limit: None, with_vals: None, reverse: None, start: None, end: None }

My hope is to be able to have spans automtically generate IDs, automatically reference their parent span IDs if they have one, and logs would include the ID of the current span.

Span IDs aren't particularly useful in human readable logs. Either spans are naturally delimited, in which case you don't need them; or they're often interleaved, in which case associating them by eye is tedious and cumbersome. More often you have a particular tool to view traces in an organized way and thus your output format is tied to it (e.g. a profiler like tracy or coz, or some opentelemetry tool).

Just making sure you know what you're asking. Logs and spans are already linked behind the scenes but not displayed by your subscriber. I can write an answer that does what you want but will likely require a custom event formatter.

@kmdreko sorry for the delay, yes I'm aware for the human readable usefulness. I had tried with a .json() as you can see commented out, and they did not appear there. As such I didn't believe IDs were being generated anywhere, but maybe the .json() does not print them, and if I added say an otel subscriber like you mentioned it would use them as needed when shipping like you mentioned. I just wanted to see them to verify they were being more than just logs!

"As such I didn't believe IDs were being generated anywhere" - you can see that Ids are required when implementing a Subscriber. "if I added say an otel subscriber like you mentioned it would use them as needed" - yes.

@kmdreko would it be possible to at least output the parent span id easily? Then it's easy to go from log -> trace when moving from say loki to tempo for example

IDs are being generated for spans and their parents, but your subscriber just doesn't show them.
Span IDs aren't particularly useful in human readable logs. Either spans are naturally delimited for your use-case, in which case you don't need them; or they're often interleaved, in which case associating them by eye is tedious and cumbersome. More often you have a particular tool to view traces in an organized way and thus your output format is tied to it (e.g. a profiler like tracy or coz, or some opentelemetry tool).
But here is a demonstration how you could log the span ID with your message by creating your own FormatEvent implementation for use with an existing tracing-subscriber. This is adapted from the example here, so you may look there or at the source of other implementations for more ideas.
use tracing::{Event, Subscriber};
use tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::{self, FormatEvent, FormatFields};
use tracing_subscriber::fmt::time::{FormatTime, SystemTime};
use tracing_subscriber::fmt::FmtContext;
use tracing_subscriber::registry::LookupSpan;

struct MyFormatter;

impl<S, N> FormatEvent<S, N> for MyFormatter
where
    S: Subscriber + for<'a> LookupSpan<'a>,
    N: for<'a> FormatFields<'a> + 'static,
{
    fn format_event(
        &self,
        ctx: &FmtContext<'_, S, N>,
        mut writer: format::Writer<'_>,
        event: &Event<'_>,
    ) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let metadata = event.metadata();

        write!(&mut writer, "[")?;
        SystemTime.format_time(&mut writer)?;
        write!(&mut writer, "]")?;

        write!(&mut writer, " {} {}", metadata.level(), metadata.target())?;

        if let Some(span) = ctx.parent_span() {
            write!(&mut writer, " span={:?}", span.id())?;
        }

        write!(&mut writer, ": ")?;
        ctx.field_format().format_fields(writer.by_ref(), event)?;

        writeln!(writer)
    }
}

fn main() {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt().event_format(MyFormatter).init();

    tracing::info!("no span");

    let _span = tracing::info_span!("my_span", answer = 42).entered();
    tracing::info!(
        question = "life, the universe, and everything",
        "hello world"
    );
}

[2024-06-26T16:54:21.851457Z] INFO mycrate: no span
[2024-06-26T16:54:21.853566Z] INFO mycrate span=Id(1): hello world question="life, the universe, and everything"


Thanks, would a span id really be “1”? That seems like it would easily conflict.

@danthegoodman The Subscriber is the one responsible for generating the IDs. In this context, yes, the tracing-subscriber fmt implementation is purely application local and thus the spans are only meaningful within the currently running program (conflicts with other programs or other invocations are not considered at all). But again, if you use a subscriber designed to work across multiple programs/invocations, like opentelemetry, this ID might be more random (or might not since local IDs can be mapped to a global ID when exported fairly trivially).

Ah ok cool, thanks for all the help!!
